# How to keep HTML label text next to an input in mobile browser?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I use `input` and `label` to construct these two controls. They looks good in desktop browsers.

[image]

The structure is simply:

```
<div>  
  <input id=""></input>
  <label for=""><span></span></label>
</div>
```

In the css, the `label` is `display:inline-block`, `input` and `div` are `display:block`

But when it is displayed in a mobile browser, it becomes less pleasing

[image]

Is there anyway I can force the label to display next to the input?

Comment: Tried reducing `font-size` at mobile display ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div>  
  <label>
    <input id=""></input>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might out of topic. If you are using bootstrap. You can do like this example.

Check my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4c9dcsxj/)

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/> Choice 1 The text really long </label>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/> Choice 2 The text really long </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

```
 <label class=""><input type="checkbox" id=""><span>Label for the check box </span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with positioning.

```
<div>  
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label for=""><span>Choice 1 the text is really long</span></label>
</div>

div { 
    position: relative; 
}
input { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}
label { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 1.3em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oy48xphp/1/